# Calling PostgreSQL function that returns table in Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I have the following query:

```
WITH matching_data as (
 select * from consultants_matching_data_for_project(6001)
)

select 
  id,
  matching_data.city_matching

from 
  consultant_profiles
LEFT OUTER JOIN matching_data on matching_data.consultant_profile_id = consultant_profiles.id;
```

Is there any other way to join with matching_data result without using a WITH clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no need for the CTE anyway, nor a subquery. You can use the function just like a table:

```
SELECT
  consultant_profiles.id,
  matching_data.city_matching
FROM
  consultant_profiles
LEFT JOIN consultants_matching_data_for_project(6001) AS matching_data
  ON matching_data.consultant_profile_id = consultant_profiles.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like suquery works fine:

```
SELECT
  consultant_profiles.id,
  matching_data.city_matching
FROM
  consultant_profiles
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM consultants_matching_data_for_project(6001)
  ) AS matching_data
  ON matching_data.consultant_profile_id = consultant_profiles.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the function call directly to the `from` clause of the outer query:

```
SELECT p.id, x.city_matching
FROM consultant_profiles p
LEFT JOIN consultants_matching_data_for_project(6001) x 
    ON x.consultant_profile_id = p.id;
```

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS):

> SQL Functions as Table Sources: All SQL functions can be used in the FROM clause of a query